# input number increasing every time train.dataset is called

Tags: python, tensorflow

My model has multiple inputs and outputs so I'm passing a dictionary to train_dataset:

```
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    (
        {"input_17": timetr, "input_18": atr},
        {"ed": wtr, "sd": wbtr},
    )
)
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(10)
```

Now, everytime I run the above code block  and then run:

```
history = model.fit(train_dataset,epochs=5,callbacks=[cp_callback],verbose=1,steps_per_epoch= 402)
```

It will ask to me increment the input number i.e. `"input_17"` should be `"input_19"` and `"input_18"` should be `"input_20"`. I don't know why this is happening , also I'm tired of incrementing the inputs every time I run both these commands. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It creates a new incremental name for each run. Previous names are already used, so the suffix will be increased to assign a new name. Try to specify name yourself like:

```
InputLayer(...,name="input_1")
InputLayer(...,name="input_2")
```

Then their names will be the same every time you run.